# Connect to existing Graph DB in Neo4J Desktop

Tags: neo4j, desktop

Probably a dumb qustion but I can't find a way to connect an existing graph DB via neo4j desktop. Google throw some results but I cannot believe that I need to import the DB into the desktop. Isn't there a way to connect?

I tried also to change

```
dbms.active_database=myExistingDB.db

dbms.directories.data=C:/MyNeoDB/
```

but desktop still looks into the very hidden and complicated path like

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\neo4j-community-3.5.4\data\databases\neo4jDatabases\database-245a74d1-47d5-43dc-9ffd-7ad04b78eda9\installation-3.5.5
```

Even copying the old database to this place didnt work as the db is empty when started.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

In Neo4J Desktop, select your project -> Add Graph -> Connect to Remote Graph. Enter your username & password and you should be able to correct to the remote graph.

Comment: This is what I tried, but I end with "Unable to establish remote connection: DB is unreachable with specified config"." and "Service unavailable". The Connect URL is "bolt://localhost:7687". Maybe the DB needs to be in a certain directory? Or do I need to start a service before?

Comment: Wait, is this a remote or local db you're trying to connect to? That looks like a local connection string, in which case you probably want to select Add Graph -> Create a Local Graph, instantiate it with a name and then restore from backup via neo4j-admin (using [restore](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup/restoring/) if you're running Enterprise, or [load](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/) if you're running Community)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I always work local on the test systems. I read the docu but I was not able to identify a neo4j-admin command file in /bin. I run on the live server Neo4j CE 3.2.7 - maybe this version has a different dump-process? The neo4j docu unfortunately also describes the usage of neo4j-admin which I haven't.

Comment: As far as I know, neo4j-admin comes with both Community and Enterprise editions. You can check the relevant docs for path information, depending on your platform & installation method - https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/

Comment: Thank you for the link - I have checked the whole live server for neo4j-admin but there was no match - strange enough. You do not have by chance a link to this older version for a reinstallment mabye?

Comment: You mention a live server - I thought we were talking about a local database, on your desktop machine / laptop?  
Maybe it would help if you could describe your setup in more detail, neo4j-admin is part of the current release, not an older version.